# swap pointers in C - incompatible warning

Tags: c, pointers

the function swap does the work, it swap successfully, but I got a warning and I dont know why.

```
void swap(char **a,char **b) {
        char * temp = *a;
        *a=*b;
        *b=temp;
}

void function() {
    char ** arr[max]; // this is an array of pointers of pointers
    .....

    swap(&arr[0],&arr[1]);
}
```

warning: passing argument 1 of  א swap א  from incompatible pointer type
warning: passing argument 2 of  א swap א  from incompatible pointer type

Comment: That's hardly what you **really** want, as it leads to 3-star programming which is **not** a compliment. As general advice: if you need more than 2 stars anywhere in your code, you should check the design.

Comment: @Olaf , i am a computer science student, and we uses 3 star in our homeworkes and lessons.

Comment: I'm an embedded systems engineer with >30 years of professional programming including C and ca. 10 other languages. I also taught C programming to studentds at university. And I say there is something wrong with your architecture and interfaces if you use 3-star code in production code! Bad tutors and bad programmers otoh are not that rare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr[0]` is a pointer to a pointer (`char**`). `&arr[0]` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer (`char***`), but your function expects `char**`.

Corrected function:

```
void swap(char ***a,char ***b) {
    char **temp = *a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=temp;
}
```

Comment: Being a 3-star C programmer is not a compliment.That's most likely not what OP really should use.

Comment: @Olaf Since we do not know what problem is he trying to solve, the best answer we can furnish is the most direct answer to his direct question.